# Binding element 'children' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript, react-native

I notice that below code should be `js` coding style, how could I write in the `tsx` style ?

```
import React, { Children } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';


export function Heading ({children, props}){
    return <Text{...props}>{children}</Text>
}
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) + [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this code

```
    export function Heading ({children, props}:{children:any,props:any}){
        return <Text{...props}>{children}</Text>
    }
```